# Objects are not being pushed to array properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have an event listener which listens for new messages, and I want to push all new messages to an array, but when I check the result I see that **only the strings** are being pushed.

This is my code :

```js
async function consume() {
  try {
    let result = [];
    const connection = await amqps.connect(URL);
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.consume("messages", function (message) {
      result.push(JSON.parse(message.content.toString()));
    });
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

When I call the consume method and check the result, this is what is returned:

```sh
[
  'yoyo',   'yoyo',
  'yoyo',   'yoyo',
  'yoyo',   'yoyo',
  '',       'hi you',
  'hi you', 'hi you',
  'hi you', 'hi you',
  'hi you', 'hi you'
]
```

However, when I log `JSON.parse(message.content.toString())` from within the listener function I can see the objects:

```sh
...
hi you
hi you
hi you
{
  read: false,
  timeSent: 1645945954348,
  message: 'Hchxh',
  userID: 41,
  contactID: 46
}
{
  read: false,
  timeSent: 1645945990969,
  message: 'Gry',
  userID: 41,
  contactID: 46
}
...
```

Here is the result when logging `message.content.toString()` (without parsing) from within the listener:

```sh
"hi you"
"hi you"
"hi you"
{"read":false,"timeSent":1645945954348,"message":"Hchxh","userID":41,"contactID":46}
{"read":false,"timeSent":1645945990969,"message":"Gry","userID":41,"contactID":46}
{"read":false,"timeSent":1645946032914,"message":"Ti","userID":41,"contactID":46}
{"read":false,"timeSent":1645946119720,"message":"Ge","userID":41,"contactID":46}
{"read":false,"timeSent":1645946454158,"message":"Beuh","userID":41,"contactID":46}
{"read":false,"timeSent":1645948170050,"message":"Xhxh","userID":41,"contactID":46}
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to come close to your input :) What is `.content` on your message argument?

Comment: It returns a buffer from rabbitMQ queue. ```toString()``` converts it to readable text.

Comment: does `.consume` return a promise?

Comment: Yes. Without await it returns an empty array.

Comment: What does message.content.toString() give? a string, an array or an object?

Comment: it returns a string.

Comment: Can you share one of that string?

Comment: Added the result of ```toString()```

Comment: The result you give of `toString()` is not valid JSON, so `JSON.parse` would error on it. Please be careful in providing the *exact* output you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
async function consume() {
  try {
    const connection = await amqps.connect(URL);
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    const result = await channel.consume('messages');
    return result.content.toString();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

You can parse it if you want even though I'm not sure why you'd need to.

Comment: I just tried this. Not sure why, but it did not work. Could be a rabbitMQ thing.